# Is there any shorthand one-parameter function syntax in R?

Tags: r

Is there a more compact way to write simple functions like this?

```
function(x) {return(0.01 * x)}
```

So for example in Scala this would be `0.01 * _`.

Comment: No. This is not a feature of the core R language. You'd have to use some custom function/package to create an alternative syntax that you would want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be simplified in `tidyverse` with `~`.  Here, we specify the columns to transform/mutate/modify as the first two columns, then use the anonymous function call `~`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
      mutate_at(1:2, ~ 0.01 * .)
```

If we are creating as a function, use the `as_mapper`

```
library(purrr)
f1 <- as_mapper(~ 0.01 * .)
mtcars %>%
     mutate_at(1:2, f1)
```

Comment: For OP, in many tidyverse functions they automatically call `as_mapper` so you don't have to, but that's not the case for base functions

Comment: @CalumYou  yes, I meant if the OP wanted to create a standalone function with minimal code